# Docker: reducing parent images (how big is too big)?

Tags: docker, containers, jupyter-notebook, filesize, docker-image

big newbie to Docker here, so forgive if the question is unclear:

I am trying to build my own Jupyter notebook image, at the simplest level this is just:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook
RUN pip install keras
```

When I build this image (lets call it keras-notebook), I understand that I have 2 images locally, the parent image **jupyter/scipy-notebook** and my **keras-notebook**.

Unfortunately, this leaves me with 2 4GB+ images stored locally - how can I build my keras-notebook without having to have a local jupyter/scipy-notebook?

The bigger question I also have is, how big is too big for a Docker image? Most people suggest a recommended image size of 100s of MB and these images are in the range of GB - so is that (almost) defeating the point of containerizing this software?

Comment: You are probably misunderstand how docker layers work.  jupyter/scipy-noteback is 4GB+.  It is composed of `n` layers:  `layer_1, layer_2, ..., layer_n`.  keras_notebook is composed of `n+1` layers: `layer_1, layer_2, ..., layer_n, layer_n+1`.  Since the first `n` layers are identical and docker knows it, having both images does not require 8GB+ of local storage.  It requires 4GB+ (a tiny bit more than just having jupyter/scipynotebook).  The corollary is that you can't really save any space by removing jupyter/scipy-notebook.

Comment: Yes you're right ... I just realised I've been misreading the output of `docker images` incorrectly and misattributing the image size with the size that was been taken up

Answer (score 0):

If your base image is big, your custom container will be bigger.

There is no right or wrong on building images, just the optimal, to illustrate that: think about the download time of a 4gb image and a 100mb one that does the same thing, of course you will use the 100mb one.

Making images smaller is a challenge to most image builders.